# Unstable sets in a chaotic attractor

Tags: chaos-theory

I am having a hard time understanding the discussion of chaotic sets on invariant manifolds as given in *Chaos in Dynamical Systems* by Edward Ott.

If the invariant manifold of a particular system contains a chaotic attractor $A$, then the transverse Lyapunov exponent $h$ will generally depend on the intial condition $\mathbf{x}_0$, with $\mathbf{x_0}$ an arbitrary point on the invariant manifold. They then state that one can typically identify the following two distinct exponents, $$\hat{h} = \mathrm{max}_{\mathbf{x_0}\in A}\left[h(\mathbf{x}_0 )\right],$$ $$h_* = h(\mathbf{x}_0) \quad \mathrm{for} \quad \mathbf{x}_0 \in A \ \ \mathrm{typical}.$$

In other words $h_*$ corresponds to the set of $\mathbf{x}_0$ that are typical with respect to the natural measure, and $\hat{h}$ corresponds with the set of $\mathbf{x}_0$ that maximize $h$. Now the book states the following,

*"Thus, if one were to 'close one's eyes and put one's finger down randomly at a point on the invariant manifold' then the maximal transverse Lyapunov exponent generated by following the orbit from this point would be  $h_*$."*

To me this statement seems to suggest that all points on the manifold are indeed typical with respect to the natural measure. Later however the book states that those points on the manifold that are not typical, and thus do not produce a Lyapunov exponent $h_*$ are interesting since they correspond with unstable orbits. This is where I get confused, are these points still on the manifold even though the set containing them has natural measure zero? I feel like my confusion stems from me not fully grasping the concept of a natural measure yet, so any help there would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just so we know where to begin explaining: Are you familiar with basic measure theory and zero measure, e.g., that ℚ has measure zero within ℝ?

Comment: My first introduction into measure theory came with this course, so my knowledge is sadly limited. The natural measure has been explained to me as follows. If one were to cover the entire manifold with "boxes", then if the time spent inside each box is the same for trajectories starting from every initial condition this time defines the natural measure. Thus a set of natural measure zero would never be visited by any trajectories, if I interpret this correctly.

Additionally, a typical point with respect to a measure is a point that is not part of the set which is zero valued by that measure